# Control Panel Speed

Tags: control-panel, admin, speed

There are many articles of advice about how to speed up the front end of an EE site, but very little about how to improve the performance of the Control Panel.

A client is constantly telling me their site's CP is slow. They're on a shared hosting plan - *at times* it does take a long time to load certain CP pages - such as adding and editing entries.

- Are there any hard, fast rules to speed up the CP?
- Is CP speed directly related to which addons are used / the amount of custom fields per entry?
- Does a faster server mean a faster CP?
- What would be an expected CP page load time?

I've just got a "Script executed in 0.5080 seconds - 211 SQL queries used" which seems pretty good, doesn't it? But the client reports (and I can confirm) that sometime page loads are 10 seconds plus+.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Does a faster server mean a faster CP?*

**YES**
In your case is "shared hosting" - sometimes can happens that some site which share the same resources (DB or CPU) just take it all. So best advice for this - change hosting.

*Are there any hard, fast rules to speed up the CP?*

On shared hosting is not too much ways to speed up CP. 
You need to analyse CP page one-by-one to find possible cure/reason.

For example you can try to disable Ellislab news/new version feed update.

If  your publish page works slow - you can check if you don't have too many authors. Some site give  authors right for Member group, but spammers can create thousandth accounts. As result - you will have a huge mysql select.

etc.

*Is CP speed directly related to which addons are used / the amount of custom fields per entry?*

**YES**  - some accessories or ext. can made your CP work slow.

*What would be an expected CP page load time?*

Is dependent on server resources/settings / specific CP page content.